# How does Salesforce deal with License removal?

Tags: administration, user, licenses, user-admin

If I have 3 users in my org, I remove a license, so I now have 2 licenses, I still see 3 assigned with -1 licenses available.

Will Salesforce still let all three users login or will one or the users no longer have access? If so, how does Salesforce determine which user can no longer log in?

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand **I remove a license**. I'm assuming that you have unchecked the active field on user record. If you have unchecked and saved it, you should really see only 2 active licenses.

On user record, there is a field called active. If that field is checked, the user can longer login to your org.

Comment: The OP contacted SF and reduced the number of paid salesforce licenses

Comment: That mean you agreed for 2 lisence it will be a complience issue. And your account manager will contant you to deactivate one of them as soon as possiable